# Load React JS component from external script in "run time"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm using React JS + webpack.
General case that I need to resolve is to dynamically load React components that were not bundled with main application. Kind of pluggable components that can be developed independently from main app and then loaded by application dynamically, without rebuilding whole app.

Particular case is below.

I have two completely separated modules (i.e. built using different package.json and webpack.config.js):

- The `MainApp`
- Some `Component`

I need to implement following behaviour:

1. Page with `MainApp` loaded and initialized.
2. `MainApp` dynamicaly lookup for url of .js file that contains `Component` (e.g. by making GET request to web-server).
3. `MainApp` loads .js file with `Component` and include it to page as `<script>`
4. `MainApp` uses loaded `Component` while rendering.

Is such use-case possible in react js + webpack?

Comment: The GET request returns a compiled component?

Comment: It returns valid .js file, not .jsx (if you are talking about it).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope. I found another solution for my particular task, but it doesn't solve general problem. I creating components dynamically from json description (like https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form). It makes dynamic components quite limited in appearance and behaviour, but it's ok for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With webpack 5 you can now do this via [module federation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/).

The basic idea is that you "expose" exports from one project to be used in another:

**App 1 (uses Button from app2)**

```html
<!-- public/index.html -->
<html>

<head>
  <!-- remote reference to app 2 -->
  <script src="http://localhost:3002/remoteEntry.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
//app.ts
import * as React from "react";

const RemoteButton = React.lazy(() => import("app2/Button"));

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Typescript</h1>
    <h2>App 1</h2>
    <React.Suspense fallback="Loading Button">
      <RemoteButton />
    </React.Suspense>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

```js
//... webpack.config.js
plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "app1",
      library: { type: "var", name: "app1" },
      remotes: {
        app2: "app2",
      },
      shared: ["react", "react-dom"],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
    }),
  ]
```

**App 2 (exposes Button)**

```
// src/Button.ts
import * as React from "react";

const Button = () => <button>App 2 Button</button>;

export default Button;
```

```js
//... webpack.config.js
 plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "app2",
      library: { type: "var", name: "app2" },
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        Button: "./src/Button",
      },
      shared: ["react", "react-dom"],
    })
  ]
```

Here is a [repo containing various examples](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples).

Comment: I have the same needs. I need to use an external .js file which itself include a react component to be used in a main react application. External .js file is loaded dynamically at runtime when neede. I configured webpack to have externals react and react-dom. But each time the external .js is loaded I get the folowing error: "[ReferenceError: react is not defined]". How can I allow external .js file to refer the react libraries in the main application? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are asking how to externalize React. If so, you can list libraries as "externals" in your `webpack.config.js` file:

```
webpackConfig.externals = {
  "react": "React",
  "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
  ...
}
```

Comment: I need to load component that wasn't exists at "compile time" (well, bundling time). I think you're talking about lazy-loading so all components are already known when app is bundled. It's not the same