# Dynamically load a React component/bundle from external source

Tags: reactjs, webpack, dynamic

What I want to achieve is allow people to author and build their own React content (assume that this content is trusted as it will be served up from my own APIs) and to then load that content dynamically into my React UI.

I've been hunting around trying to find a way to get this working, but I'm missing the final piece to make it work, or it may not be possible.

So imagine I have my already bundled UI deployed and running with a basic app like: (I've omitted module imports for brevity)

```
const App = () => (
  <h1>My App</h1>
  <DynamicContent />
);
```

...so for the dynamic content component I want to be able to load the external source - I've seen `react-loadable` mentioned a lot, so hoping this helps:

```
const DynamicComponent = () => (
  state = { content: null };

  componentDidMount() {
    const content = Loadable({
      loader: () => import(fetch('http://localhost:3000/dynamic')),
      loading: () => <div>Loading { m }...</div>,
    });
    this.setState({ content });
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.content;
  }
);
```

If we then assume that hitting `http://localhost:3000/dynamic` returns the string of a component like this:

```
const MyContent = () => <h2>Dynamic Content</h2>;

export default MyContent;
```

What I am finding is that no matter what format I returned the fetched JS in (raw JSX as above, fully-transpiled JS or webpack bundle) the content does not render.

The only way I can make dynamic content render is if it's existing content in the UI code base that's code split via a relative file import e.g. `import('./DynamicContent')`.

Is this even possible? It feels like it should be, but I'm clearly missing something in my understanding. Perhaps there's a solution involving SSR, but I can'd find a helpful example that puts the pieces in place that I need.

Thanks.

Comment: you can check how code splitting works (https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) I hope it will give some ideas

Comment: Hi @MikhailTokarev I updated the question above to say that the only way that this works for me is if I use code-splitting and the "dynamic" content is actually already part of the UI code base during webpack bundling. However if this content is not available until run-time then I cannot find a way to load this on-demand.

Comment: What does http://localhost:3000/dynamic return exactly? HTML string or JS bundle?

Comment: @rupil I've tried JSX string, transpiled JS string and JS webpack bundle.

Comment: @Michael have you resolved this problem? I'm facing a similar situation

Comment: @NicolasDominguez not yet - I parked this work for the time being.

Comment: @Michael, ok, if you resume your project, take a look at this https://github.com/TroyAlford/react-jsx-parser

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51482929/rendering-external-html-react-components-dynamically-in-react

Comment: @NicolasDominguez thanks, will take a look.

Comment: webpacks new module federation might solve your problem.  Check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61823689/800619

Comment: i'm also looking to do something similar. any other solutions that you're ran across?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use "React.Suspense".   change App.js  as below

```
const App = () => (
  <h1>My App</h1>
  <React.Suspense fallback="Loading...">
     <DynamicContent />
  </React.Suspense >
);
```