# Exclude some components while building reactjs app

Tags: reactjs

I have ReactJS webapp ready for building.
Now I want to build this app but do not need some components at present but will need them in future. So, ho could I exclude the unrequired components while building the application?

Comment: I would just remove them and then revert them from git

Comment: Checkout this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61823689/13603449) maybe this is what you are seeking for